# Does this function converge uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence

does $f_n=$$x^n\over \sqrt[4]{n} $ converges uniformly for x $\in$[0,1]

I find a hard tim finding $f(x)$ is it 0 for x $\in$[0,1] the problem is at $f(1)$ is it 0 or $\infty$ 
From the graph it looks like it converges uniformly but is it correct, if so what is $f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $0 \le f_n(x) \le f_n(1)$. What does $f_n(1) = 1/\sqrt[4](n)$ do as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: got it so $f(x)$should be 0 within the given interval